# last element of ListItem is not clickable

Tags: react-native

I have an Array containing data , I am rendering that data inside ListItem of react native elements , every thing seems good except the on press Event , the last item of my ListItem component does not working on press event , for the others items the click works just fine
could you please help me to solve that issue , here is my code

```
 onChangeLan(lanz) {
    this.setState({ loc : lanz});

   this.props.languaje(lanz.locale);

  }
  mydata(){
    //this.state.storg = false
  switch(this.state.storg){
     case false : 
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}  onLayout={this._onLayout}>

        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
            </View>
            <View style={{marginHorizontal : 10,marginTop : 2}}>


            {
            this.state.data.map( (lan) =>{

             return(
              <ListItem 
              key = {lan.id}
              title= {I18n.t(lan.name)}
              onPress = { this.onChangeLan.bind(this,lan)}
              rightIcon={this.showIcons(lan)}
              containerStyle={{backgroundColor : '#BBE9FD',marginVertical : 2}}
              />

              )
            })
          }
           </View>
                </ScrollView>        
        </View>
    );
    default :
    return <ActivityIndicator /> 
  }

  }
  render() {
      return  this.mydata();

  }
```

Comment: did you tried console log

Comment: @sachin yes for all items it works except as i said last one , there is nothing shown on console log

Comment: may be you are getting an empty object in last item

Comment: sachin but data is displayed completly in view, i think if there is an empty object there will be nothing to click on

Comment: @salmanaacvf please show `console.log(this.state.data)`

Comment: this is the console.log results , 0: {id: 0, locale: "en", name: "engl"}
1: {id: 1, locale: "es", name: "spanih"}
2: {id: 2, locale: "fr", name: "fren"}
3: {id: 3, locale: "ar", name: "arab"}

Comment: but the last item is not clickable at all